# Nuxt routing double optional params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, parameters, nuxt.js, router

I have nuxt app. I want to create path like this:

`path: '/dworzec-pkp/:slug/:category?/:date?',`

So there would be two optional params. Example urls would be:

- `localhost:5555/dworzec-pkp/nowa-iwiczna` <-- w/o optional params
- `localhost:5555/dworzec-pkp/nowa-iwiczna/12-10-2020` <-- optional param: date
- `localhost:5555/dworzec-pkp/nowa-iwiczna/departures` <-- optional param: category
- `localhost:5555/dworzec-pkp/nowa-iwiczna/departures/12-10-2020` <-- optional params: date & category

How do I know if url contain category or date? Should I create just directories `dworzec-pkp/_slug` and within it `_.vue` file, and then programmatically decide whether it is `date` or `category`? Or maybe there's some better solution for that?

---

Currently I tried like this:

[image]

and my issue is that when i enter this `localhost:5555/dworzec-pkp/nowa-iwiczna/12-10-2020` then it is treated as `:category?`. Also I would need to basically almost copy-paste entire _date.vue and index.vue there as this pages are almost same.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I posted an issue on Nuxt as there is no simple way of achieving it. However, there is a workaround with middleware routing. Someone responded with a potential solution. I haven't had a chance to try it yet but i'll come back with a full answer when I do. See their solution here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9732